# Exchange Server 2010 SP1

Tags: windows, exchange-2010

I am having trouble getting my Hub Transport Rules to stop emails from leaving my organization. Currently I have the rule stopping people in certain distro groups from sending emails outside the organization. I set the rule to be enabled and put my user account into the group yet am still able to send off site. I even put mail enabled security groups into the distros and put myself in the security group and applied the rule with no luck. Does anyone have any ideas on what may be stopping this. Our Exchange server does connect to our proxy to get off domain. Could there be a connection fault there?

Comment: Hi, did you logoff and login back to test ? Group membership dont refresh automaticly for an account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my test, before/after adding users to this group, if we create transport rules to block external emails which are sent from a member of a distribution group the rule may not work immdiately(or not work at all).

However, we could try restarting **MS Exchange Transport service** to speed up this modification.

[image]

After restarting this service, the transport rule should work well after a short time, and the external emails from members of a specific group will be blocked.

Comment: I found out that the security groups I had in the distros weren't set up by my networks installers. So once I attached emails to them the members in the groups started to get blocked. But the service did help! Thank you for your assistance.